# Mathematica data to python session

Tags: external-calls

I am doing some work and the last part of it needs to be done in python. All I need is to transfer a list of numeric higher rank tensors that I generated in the mathematica notebook to python. I am trying to use external session, but I don't find in the documentation how can I carry the variables from the notebook, that is x = {tensor, tensor,...}, into the external evaluate. The documentation only shows you the other way around, a result from external evaluate to mathematica, through the output.

Comment: Please give an example of a numeric higher rank tensor. You give no Mathematica code.

Comment: It is in the question: "x = {tensor, tensor, ...}" the tensors in the list start at rank1 and increase. I did not specify it further because I am looking for general solutions.